# Unable to access resources from project root within tests

Tags: go

I have a simple `Go` project with the following structure:

```bash
.
├── config/
│   └── application.yaml
...
├── internal/
│   └── config/
│       ├── application.go
│       ├── application_test.go
│       └── database.go
└── app.go
```

The function that reads the configuration file(s) is implemented like:

```golang
func Load() *Config { // Config is a struct that resembles the YAML structure
    sourceFiles := []string{
        filepath.Join("config", "application.yaml"),
        filepath.Join("config", os.ExpandEnv("application-${APP_ENV}.yaml")),
    }
    // Custom configuration settings for config
    if err := config.LoadFiles(sourceFiles...); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(...)
    }
    configuration := new(Config)
    if err := config.Decode(configuration); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(...)
    }
    return configuration
}
```

Everything works file, until I started writing test cases. For instance, I read the (`YAML`) configuration files within `internal/config/application.go`. My assumption is that because the process that runs the application starts from the project root, it's able to find the configuration files by just using `filepath.Join("config" , "application-$APP_ENV.yaml")`...but as soon as I try to call the same function from `application_test.go`, it's unable to do so — again, my assumption is that for test cases, the runner starts the process at level where they are located.

The error is: `2023/08/09 11:10:04 Unable to load configuration file due to: open config/application.yaml: no such file or directory`

So my question is simple: what's the correct approach here to be able to solve this problem and have a consistent way to read those files from anywhere in the project, preferably without using any *hacky* workarounds, etc.

---

#### What I've Tried So Far

I've seen the `embed` option several times, but so far, it's not working for my use case. The entrypoint for the application is `app.go`. Propagating the embedded collection of files either declaring a variable (inside `internal/config/application.go`) and propagating that value from `app.go` wouldn't work for the tests cases because the process is not started from `main` at that point.

```golang
package main

//go:embed config/*
var embeddedFS embed.FS

func main() {
    config.EmbeddedFS = embeddedFS
    conf := config.Load()
    ...
}
```

Another solution (the ideal from my point of view) would be to try to embed the collection of files within `internal/config/application.go`, but then `Go` is unable to find the `YAML` files — path must not contain '.' or '..' path elements nor begin with a leading slash.

Using an environment variable is a never-ending game because the environment where the application run and where the test cases are executed changes frequently.

Comment: Next to your `./config/application.yaml` file you can create a `./config/embed.go` file and put the `go:embed` code there (and make sure the FS is exported), then have `./internal/config/` files import the `./config`'s package and use its embedded FS to access the yaml files.